# Ant classpath - classes created by Hibernate can't import other packages

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, classpath

I have defined a new Clock singleton in a new package "utility." Most of my code can access this as expected, given the import statement

```
import com.mydomain.app.utility.*;
```

I have some classes generated from Hibernate mappings by hbm2java, and including some additional code, inserted from a tag in the .hbm.xml file:

```
<meta attribute="class-code"><![CDATA[ .....
```

Some of my generated classes need to access the new Clock, so I tried importing the package into the generated Java code:

```
<meta attribute="extra-import">com.mydomain.app.utility.*</meta>
```

The import statement shows up as expected in the java, but the ant build chokes on it at the javac stage:

```
[javac] C:\Source\WebApp\hibernate\com\mydomain\data\app\Workflow.java:11: package com.mydomain.app.utility does not exist
[javac] import com.mydomain.app.utility.*;
[javac] ^
```

The hibernate code generation is done by a build file in the hibernate directory, which is a sibling of the application directory:

```
 root
   app 
   hibernate
   others....
```

Is there something I can put in the classpath of hibernate/build.xml that will allow the generated Java code to see the Clock class defined in app/java/com.mydomain.app/utility/Clock.java?

Or do I have to split out the Clock utility into a separate .jar and compile it first, so I can point to its .jar in hibernate/build.xml?

Or something else entirely?

What is the best approach in this situation?

Comment: Did you try with the full classname? such as 'com.mydomain.app.utility.Clock' instead 'of com.mydomain.app.utility.*'

Comment: Yes, I also tried with the full class name, and that also wouldn't resolve.

Comment: I tried defining a new build target in app/build.xml that compiles just my Clock class (and IClock interface), and calling that before the Hibernate code-generation target. Now having trouble pointing to those classes from hibernate/build.xml:

        <fileset dir="../app/classes">

      <include name="**/**/**/**/*.class" />
        </fileset>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<project name="${project.title}" basedir="./" default="all">

    <property file="build.properties" />

    <property name="path.utilities" value="${path.deploy}/utilities" />
    <property name="path.classes" value="${path.deploy}/classes" />
    <property name="path.src" value="../src" />

    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <pathelement path="${path.utilities}" />
        <pathelement path="${path.classes}" />
        <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
    </path>

    <target name="compile">
        <javac target="1.5" source="1.5" srcdir="${path.src}" destdir="${path.classes}">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

</project>
```

Can you add concerned parts of your build.xml ?

Comment: Something like this worked for me. I had to add a target to compile the utilities first, and then use qualified references to com.mydomain.app.utilities.Clock in my Hibernate-generated classes, rather than trying to import the package.

Thanks!